# Trying to make a list that counts numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a function that creates a list of 100 zeros and then generates 1000 random integers between 0 and 100 and then counts how many times each number is generated and then returns those values in the original list so lets some 0 appeared 2 times and 1 appeared 5 times the beginning of the list would be [2,5...]

I tried something but this doesn't really work I mean I know I need to put in some indexing stuff somewhere but I'm not really sure where to go next.

```
from random import*

def f():
    b=[0]*100
    x=1000
    while x>0:
        for x in b:
            b[x]=randrange(0,101)
        x-=1
    return(b)

print(f())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from random import*

def f():
    b=[0]*101
    for i in range(0, 1000):
        b[randrange(0,101)]+=1
    return b

print f()
```